# How to plot gradient descent using plotly

Tags: python, machine-learning, plotly, gradient-descent, plotly-python

I have been trying to replicate some work similar to this code below but when I try to use this data from this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv Its throwing some error. I think its because of shape but don't know exactly how to modify it.

It will be great, if you help me to resolve the issue.

Here is my Code

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import noise
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

data =  = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

z = data

import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def sliding_window(arr, window_size):
    """ Construct a sliding window view of the array"""
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    window_size = int(window_size)
    if arr.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError("need 2-D input")
    if not (window_size > 0):
        raise ValueError("need a positive window size")
    shape = (arr.shape[0] - window_size + 1,
             arr.shape[1] - window_size + 1,
             window_size, window_size)
    if shape[0] <= 0:
        shape = (1, shape[1], arr.shape[0], shape[3])
    if shape[1] <= 0:
        shape = (shape[0], 1, shape[2], arr.shape[1])
    strides = (arr.shape[1]*arr.itemsize, arr.itemsize,
               arr.shape[1]*arr.itemsize, arr.itemsize)
    return as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def cell_neighbours(arr, i, j, d):
    """Return d-th neighbors of cell (i, j)"""
    w = sliding_window(arr, 2*d+1)

    ix = np.clip(i - d, 0, w.shape[0]-1)
    jx = np.clip(j - d, 0, w.shape[1]-1)

    i0 = max(0, i - d - ix)
    j0 = max(0, j - d - jx)
    i1 = w.shape[2] - max(0, d - i + ix)
    j1 = w.shape[3] - max(0, d - j + jx)

    return w[ix, jx][i0:i1,j0:j1].ravel()

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class descent_step:
    """Class for storing each step taken in gradient descent"""
    value: float
    x_index: float
    y_index: float

def gradient_descent_3d(array,x_start,y_start,steps=50,step_size=1,plot=False):
    # Initial point to start gradient descent at
    step = descent_step(array[y_start][x_start],x_start,y_start)
    
    # Store each step taken in gradient descent in a list
    step_history = []
    step_history.append(step)
    
    # Plot 2D representation of array with startng point as a red marker
    if plot:
        matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(array,origin='lower',cmap='terrain')
        matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x_start,y_start,'ro')
    current_x = x_start
    current_y = y_start

    # Loop through specified number of steps of gradient descent to take
    for i in range(steps):
        prev_x = current_x
        prev_y = current_y
        
        # Extract array of neighbouring cells around current step location with size nominated
        neighbours=cell_neighbours(array,current_y,current_x,step_size)
        
        # Locate minimum in array (steepest slope from current point)
        next_step = neighbours.min()
        indices = np.where(array == next_step)
        
        # Update current point to now be the next point after stepping
        current_x, current_y = (indices[1][0],indices[0][0])
        step = descent_step(array[current_y][current_x],current_x,current_y)
        
        step_history.append(step)
        
        # Plot each step taken as a black line to the current point nominated by a red marker
        if plot:
            matplotlib.pyplot.plot([prev_x,current_x],[prev_y,current_y],'k-')
            matplotlib.pyplot.plot(current_x,current_y,'ro')
            
        # If step is to the same location as previously, this infers convergence and end loop
        if prev_y == current_y and prev_x == current_x:
            print(f"Converged in {i} steps")
            break
    return next_step,step_history

np.random.seed(42)
global_minimum = z.min()
indices = np.where(z == global_minimum)
print(f"Target: {global_minimum} @ {indices}")

step_size = 0
found_minimum = 99999

# Random starting point
start_x = np.random.randint(0,50)
start_y = np.random.randint(0,50)

# Increase step size until convergence on global minimum
while found_minimum != global_minimum:
    step_size += 1
    found_minimum,steps = gradient_descent_3d(z,start_x,start_y,step_size=step_size,plot=False)

print(f"Optimal step size {step_size}")
found_minimum,steps = gradient_descent_3d(z,start_x,start_y,step_size=step_size,plot=True)
print(f"Steps: {steps}")

def multiDimenDist(point1,point2):
   #find the difference between the two points, its really the same as below
   deltaVals = [point2[dimension]-point1[dimension] for dimension in range(len(point1))]
   runningSquared = 0
   #because the pythagarom theorm works for any dimension we can just use that
   for coOrd in deltaVals:
       runningSquared += coOrd**2
   return runningSquared**(1/2)
def findVec(point1,point2,unitSphere = False):
  #setting unitSphere to True will make the vector scaled down to a sphere with a radius one, instead of it's orginal length
  finalVector = [0 for coOrd in point1]
  for dimension, coOrd in enumerate(point1):
      #finding total differnce for that co-ordinate(x,y,z...)
      deltaCoOrd = point2[dimension]-coOrd
      #adding total difference
      finalVector[dimension] = deltaCoOrd
  if unitSphere:
      totalDist = multiDimenDist(point1,point2)
      unitVector =[]
      for dimen in finalVector:
          unitVector.append( dimen/totalDist)
      return unitVector
  else:
      return finalVector

def generate_3d_plot(step_history):
    # Initialise empty lists for markers
    step_markers_x = []
    step_markers_y = []
    step_markers_z = []
    step_markers_u = []
    step_markers_v = []
    step_markers_w = []
    
    for index, step in enumerate(step_history):
        step_markers_x.append(step.x_index)
        step_markers_y.append(step.y_index)
        step_markers_z.append(step.value)
        
        # If we haven't reached the final step, calculate the vector between the current step and the next step
        if index < len(steps)-1:
            vec1 = [step.x_index,step.y_index,step.value]
            vec2 = [steps[index+1].x_index,steps[index+1].y_index,steps[index+1].value]

            result_vector = findVec(vec1,vec2)
            step_markers_u.append(result_vector[0])
            step_markers_v.append(result_vector[1])
            step_markers_w.append(result_vector[2])
        else:
            step_markers_u.append(0.1)
            step_markers_v.append(0.1)
            step_markers_w.append(0.1)
    
    # Include cones at each marker to show direction of step, scatter3d is to show the red line between points and surface for the terrain
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Cone(
        x=step_markers_x,
        y=step_markers_y,
        z=step_markers_z,
        u=step_markers_u,
        v=step_markers_v,
        w=step_markers_w,
        sizemode="absolute",
        sizeref=2,
        anchor='tail'),

        go.Scatter3d(
        x=step_markers_x,
        y=step_markers_y,
        z=step_markers_z,
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(
            color='red',
            width=2
        )),

        go.Surface(colorscale=terrain,z=world,opacity=0.5)])


    # Z axis is limited to the extent of the terrain array
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Gradient Descent Steps',
        scene = dict(zaxis = dict(range=[world.min(),world.max()],),),)
    return fig
    
# Generate 3D plot from previous random starting location
fig = generate_3d_plot(steps)
HTML(plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='random_starting_point_3d_gradient_descent.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

Comment: you have an extra comma (,) in the beginning of the first row that should be removed.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. I am able to read the data but I couldn't converge. Its throwing Value error here while found_minimum != global_minimum:
    step_size += 1
    found_minimum,steps = gradient_descent_3d(z,start_x,start_y,step_size=step_size,plot=False)

Comment: ok then find out the exact line which throws ValueError.

Comment: what are the values of found_minimum/global_minimum? print them before comparison.

Comment: hard to guess without looking at your code. you can use debugger (pdb) and trace your values before error occurs.

Comment: Updated my question with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because `found_minimum` is an `int`, but `global_minimum` is a `Series`.  I think the tutorial you're referencing assumes that the data is loaded as a numpy `array`, but it is never explicitly stated.

So, `z = data.to_numpy()` solves one problem and reveals another which is that the tutorial dataset is 50x50 and your data is 25x25.  It's tempting to just change the limits of the random starting point, but this doesn't end up working well.  The dataset is just too small for this implementation of gradient descent to appropriately converge.

To get around *this* issue, I just altered your dataset to manufacture a 50x50 set:

```
data_arr = data.to_numpy()
double_arr = np.append(data_arr, 1.5*data_arr + 50, axis=0)
quad_arr = np.append(double_arr, 1.5*double_arr + 50, axis=1)
```

Passing this `quad_arr` as needed throughout the code as well as updating the plotly colorscale to `go.Surface(colorscale=Earth)` gives:

[image: gradient_descent_terrain]

Full, copy-pastable code:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import noise
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

data_arr = data.to_numpy()
double_arr = np.append(data_arr, 1.5*data_arr + 50, axis=0)
quad_arr = np.append(double_arr, 1.5*double_arr + 50, axis=1)

z = quad_arr
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(z,origin='lower',cmap='terrain')

# Find maximum value index in numpy array
indices = np.where(z == z.max())
max_z_x_location, max_z_y_location = (indices[1][0],indices[0][0])
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(max_z_x_location,max_z_y_location,'ro',markersize=15)

# Find minimum value index in numpy array
indices = np.where(z == z.min())
min_z_x_location, min_z_y_location = (indices[1][0],indices[0][0])
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(min_z_x_location,min_z_y_location,'yo',markersize=15)

import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def sliding_window(arr, window_size):
    """ Construct a sliding window view of the array"""
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    window_size = int(window_size)
    if arr.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError("need 2-D input")
    if not (window_size > 0):
        raise ValueError("need a positive window size")
    shape = (arr.shape[0] - window_size + 1,
             arr.shape[1] - window_size + 1,
             window_size, window_size)
    if shape[0] <= 0:
        shape = (1, shape[1], arr.shape[0], shape[3])
    if shape[1] <= 0:
        shape = (shape[0], 1, shape[2], arr.shape[1])
    strides = (arr.shape[1]*arr.itemsize, arr.itemsize,
               arr.shape[1]*arr.itemsize, arr.itemsize)
    return as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def cell_neighbours(arr, i, j, d):
    """Return d-th neighbors of cell (i, j)"""
    w = sliding_window(arr, 2*d+1)

    ix = np.clip(i - d, 0, w.shape[0]-1)
    jx = np.clip(j - d, 0, w.shape[1]-1)

    i0 = max(0, i - d - ix)
    j0 = max(0, j - d - jx)
    i1 = w.shape[2] - max(0, d - i + ix)
    j1 = w.shape[3] - max(0, d - j + jx)

    return w[ix, jx][i0:i1,j0:j1].ravel()

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class descent_step:
    """Class for storing each step taken in gradient descent"""
    value: float
    x_index: float
    y_index: float

def gradient_descent_3d(array,x_start,y_start,steps=50,step_size=1,plot=False):
    # Initial point to start gradient descent at
    step = descent_step(array[y_start][x_start],x_start,y_start)
    
    # Store each step taken in gradient descent in a list
    step_history = []
    step_history.append(step)
    
    # Plot 2D representation of array with startng point as a red marker
    if plot:
        matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(array,origin='lower',cmap='terrain')
        matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x_start,y_start,'ro')
    current_x = x_start
    current_y = y_start

    # Loop through specified number of steps of gradient descent to take
    for i in range(steps):
        prev_x = current_x
        prev_y = current_y
        
        # Extract array of neighbouring cells around current step location with size nominated
        neighbours=cell_neighbours(array,current_y,current_x,step_size)
        
        # Locate minimum in array (steepest slope from current point)
        next_step = neighbours.min()
        indices = np.where(array == next_step)
        
        # Update current point to now be the next point after stepping
        current_x, current_y = (indices[1][0],indices[0][0])
        step = descent_step(array[current_y][current_x],current_x,current_y)
        
        step_history.append(step)
        
        # Plot each step taken as a black line to the current point nominated by a red marker
        if plot:
            matplotlib.pyplot.plot([prev_x,current_x],[prev_y,current_y],'k-')
            matplotlib.pyplot.plot(current_x,current_y,'ro')
            
        # If step is to the same location as previously, this infers convergence and end loop
        if prev_y == current_y and prev_x == current_x:
            print(f"Converged in {i} steps")
            break
    return next_step,step_history

np.random.seed(42)
global_minimum = z.min()
indices = np.where(z == global_minimum)
print(f"Target: {global_minimum} @ {indices}")

step_size = 0
found_minimum = 99999

# Random starting point
start_x = np.random.randint(0,50)
start_y = np.random.randint(0,50)

# Increase step size until convergence on global minimum
print('==========================')
print(found_minimum)
print(global_minimum)
print('==========================')

while found_minimum != global_minimum:
    step_size += 1
    try:
        found_minimum,steps = gradient_descent_3d(z,start_x,start_y,step_size=step_size,plot=True)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(f"Optimal step size {step_size}")
found_minimum,steps = gradient_descent_3d(z,start_x,start_y,step_size=step_size,plot=True)
print(f"Steps: {steps}")

def multiDimenDist(point1,point2):
   #find the difference between the two points, its really the same as below
   deltaVals = [point2[dimension]-point1[dimension] for dimension in range(len(point1))]
   runningSquared = 0
   #because the pythagarom theorm works for any dimension we can just use that
   for coOrd in deltaVals:
       runningSquared += coOrd**2
   return runningSquared**(1/2)
def findVec(point1,point2,unitSphere = False):
  #setting unitSphere to True will make the vector scaled down to a sphere with a radius one, instead of it's orginal length
  finalVector = [0 for coOrd in point1]
  for dimension, coOrd in enumerate(point1):
      #finding total differnce for that co-ordinate(x,y,z...)
      deltaCoOrd = point2[dimension]-coOrd
      #adding total difference
      finalVector[dimension] = deltaCoOrd
  if unitSphere:
      totalDist = multiDimenDist(point1,point2)
      unitVector =[]
      for dimen in finalVector:
          unitVector.append( dimen/totalDist)
      return unitVector
  else:
      return finalVector

def generate_3d_plot(step_history):
    # Initialise empty lists for markers
    step_markers_x = []
    step_markers_y = []
    step_markers_z = []
    step_markers_u = []
    step_markers_v = []
    step_markers_w = []
    
    for index, step in enumerate(step_history):
        step_markers_x.append(step.x_index)
        step_markers_y.append(step.y_index)
        step_markers_z.append(step.value)
        
        # If we haven't reached the final step, calculate the vector between the current step and the next step
        if index < len(steps)-1:
            vec1 = [step.x_index,step.y_index,step.value]
            vec2 = [steps[index+1].x_index,steps[index+1].y_index,steps[index+1].value]

            result_vector = findVec(vec1,vec2)
            step_markers_u.append(result_vector[0])
            step_markers_v.append(result_vector[1])
            step_markers_w.append(result_vector[2])
        else:
            step_markers_u.append(0.1)
            step_markers_v.append(0.1)
            step_markers_w.append(0.1)
    
    # Include cones at each marker to show direction of step, scatter3d is to show the red line between points and surface for the terrain
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Cone(
        x=step_markers_x,
        y=step_markers_y,
        z=step_markers_z,
        u=step_markers_u,
        v=step_markers_v,
        w=step_markers_w,
        sizemode="absolute",
        sizeref=2,
        anchor='tail'),

        go.Scatter3d(
        x=step_markers_x,
        y=step_markers_y,
        z=step_markers_z,
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(
            color='red',
            width=2
        )),

        go.Surface(colorscale='Earth', z=quad_arr,opacity=0.5)])


    # Z axis is limited to the extent of the terrain array
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Gradient Descent Steps',
        scene = dict(zaxis = dict(range=[quad_arr.min(),quad_arr.max()],),),)
    return fig
    
# Generate 3D plot from previous random starting location
fig = generate_3d_plot(steps)
HTML(plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='random_starting_point_3d_gradient_descent.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```